# Arduino : time scheduler is not working

Tags: input, arduino, multiprocessing

I am trying to use the Arduino time scheduler. I copied the code from [here](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/Scheduler) and I imported the library, but it didn't compile. Here's the compilation error code and the code itself:

Error:

```
In file included from time2.ino:1:
C:\arduino\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\Scheduler/Scheduler.h:62: error: 'byte' does not name a type
C:\arduino\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\Scheduler/Scheduler.h:64: error: 'NUMBER_OF_SCHEDULED_ACTIONS' was not declared in this scope
C:\arduino\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\Scheduler/Scheduler.h:65: error: 'byte' does not name a type
```

Code:

```
#include <Scheduler.h> // [url=http://playground.arduino.cc/uploads/Code/Scheduler.zip]Scheduler.zip[/url]

Scheduler scheduler = Scheduler();      //create a scheduler

const byte ledPin = 13;               //LED on pin 13

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);                 //Iitialize the UART
  pinMode(ledPin,OUTPUT);             //set pin 13 to OUTPUT
}

void loop(){
  scheduler.update();                 //update the scheduler, maybe it is time to execute a function?

  if (Serial.available()){            //if we have recieved anything on the Serial
    scheduler.schedule(setHigh,500);  //schedule a setHigh call in 500 milliseconds
    Serial.flush();                   //flush Serial so we do not schedule multiple setHigh calls
  }
}

void setHigh(){
  digitalWrite(ledPin,HIGH);          //set ledPin HIGH
  scheduler.schedule(setLow,500);     //schedule setLow to execute in 500 milliseconds
}

void setLow(){
  digitalWrite(ledPin,LOW);           //set ledPin LOW
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the library is not 1.0.0+ compliant.

Change replace the following .\Scheduler\Scheduler.h :

```js
< #include <WProgram.h>  
---  
> #if defined(ARDUINO) && ARDUINO >= 100  
> #include "Arduino.h"  
> #else  
> #include "WProgram.h"  
> #endif
```

Then it will compile, for me at least.

Comment: @mohammad You should also accept answers that work for you. This is the way to tell thanks on this site.